# JBoss twiddle errors

Tags: linux, java, jboss

First attempt to use JBoss's twiddle command line tool.  Both these commands:

```
/local/apps/jboss-as/bin $ ./twiddle.sh -H serverinfo
/local/apps/jboss-as/bin $ ./twiddle.sh -H get
```

Error to stdout:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: while resolving class: org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle
......
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.StringBuilder not found in [file:/local/apps/jboss-as/bin/twiddle.jar, file:/local/apps/jboss-as/client/jbossall-client.jar, file:/local/apps/jboss-as/client/getopt.jar, file:/local/apps/jboss-as/client/log4j.jar, file:/local/apps/jboss-as/lib/jboss-jmx.jar, file:/usr/share/java/libgcj-3.4.6.jar, file:./, core:/]
```

Is there a configuration setting anyone can recommend checking?

Reviewing:

[docs.jboss.org](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Command_Line_Access_to_JMX-Sample_twiddle_Command_Usage.html)

[twiddle reference](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/305-twiddle-reference.html?showall=1)